# SQL Filter date range query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a list of schedule records

**StaffSchedules**

[image]

Some of them were already booked.

**BookedSchedules**

[image]

Also there are some holidays

**Holidays**

[image]

I want to get only the available Staff Schedules

`Expected Schedules= StaffSchedule - BookedSchedule-Holidays`

i.e, I want row 2,6 only from StaffSchedule Table

Below is the query i tried, but it shows no results

```
with NonBookingSlots as
(
select StartdateTime,EndDateTime from Holidays
union all
select StartdateTime,EndDateTime from BookedSchedules
)

SELECT
    StaffId, StartdateTime, EndDateTime
FROM StaffSchedule
WHERE 
not exists (select 1
                from NonBookingSlots h
                where cast(StartdateTime as DATETIME) between 
                cast(h.startdatetime as DATETIME) 
                and cast(h.enddatetime as DATETIME)
           )
```

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/07698/42)

Comment: +1 for a complete question

Comment: Can a staff member's schedule be partially booked or only fully booked (as is the case with all of your example data)?

Comment: @ShWiVeL, its fully booked

Answer (score 3):

For all examples I made the assumption that the start and end times in `BookedSchedules` would match up exactly with the `StaffSchedules` start and end times.

**With CTE, similar to the question:**

I would not recommend using this query, but it may be helpful since it is similar to the query in the question. It is not very readable.

```
with NonBookingSlots as
(
  select null as StaffId,StartdateTime,EndDateTime from Holidays
  union all
  select StaffId,StartdateTime,EndDateTime from BookedSchedules
)

select
  StaffId, StartdateTime, EndDateTime
from 
  StaffSchedule
where
  not exists(
    select
      1
    from 
      NonBookingSlots
    where
      StaffSchedule.StaffId = isnull(NonBookingSlots.StaffId,StaffSchedule.StaffId)
      and (
        (
          StaffSchedule.StartDateTime =  NonBookingSlots.StartDateTime
          and StaffSchedule.EndDateTime = NonBookingSlots.EndDateTime
        ) or (
          StaffSchedule.StartDateTime <  NonBookingSlots.EndDateTime
          and StaffSchedule.EndDateTime > NonBookingSlots.StartDateTime
        )
     )
  )
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9cbf4/14

**Without CTE:**

This version is more readable in my opinion.

```
select
  StaffId, StartdateTime, EndDateTime
from 
  StaffSchedule
where
  not exists(
    select
      1
    from 
      BookedSchedules
    where
      StaffSchedule.StaffId = BookedSchedules.StaffId
      and StaffSchedule.StartDateTime =  BookedSchedules.StartDateTime
      and StaffSchedule.EndDateTime = BookedSchedules.EndDateTime
  ) and not exists(
    select
      1
    from 
      Holidays
    where
      StaffSchedule.StartDateTime <  Holidays.EndDateTime
      and StaffSchedule.EndDateTime > Holidays.StartDateTime
  )
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9cbf4/15

**With Foreign Key - What I recommend:**

If the `BookedSchedules` always match a `StaffSchedule` you should use a foreign key to the `StaffSchedule` instead of replicating the start and end times in `BookedSchedules`. This results in a cleaner and more efficient query.

```
select
  StaffId, StartdateTime, EndDateTime
from 
  StaffSchedule
where
  not exists(
    select
      1
    from 
      BookedSchedules
    where
      StaffSchedule.Id = BookedSchedules.StaffScheduleId
  ) and not exists(
    select
      1
    from 
      Holidays
    where
      StaffSchedule.StartDateTime <=  Holidays.EndDateTime
      and StaffSchedule.EndDateTime >= Holidays.StartDateTime
  )
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8a684/3

Comment: cant we make it with single where, like i tried with CTE?

Comment: @Billa do you mean you want just one EXISTS subquery?

Comment: I don't see the point of using the with clause to reduce the number of EXISTS subqueries in this case (from 2 to 1). You aren't going to reference it more than one time (one advantage of using the with clause), and you aren't simplifying the code at all (another advantage of using the with clause). Is there a particular reason you want to use one exists subquery, along with a the with clause, rather than no with clause and 2 exists subqueries?

Comment: @ShWiVeL I agree, it only seems to make it more complicated. I showed it that way to keep with how @Billa asked the question. I would recommend refactoring and using a foreign key to `StaffSchedule` in `BookedSchedules`.

Comment: @Billa I updated the answer to include a couple of alternatives. They all get the result you are looking for; however, using a foreign key would be my recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
  from dbo.StaffSchedule x
 where not exists (select 'y'
          from dbo.BookedSchedules y
         where y.staffid = x.staffid
           and y.startdatetime = x.startdatetime
           and y.enddatetime = x.enddatetime)
   and not exists (select 'z'
          from dbo.Holidays z
         where cast(z.startdatetime as date) =
               cast(x.startdatetime as date))
```

SQL Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/07698/19/0

Edit - to deal with holidays that range more than one day:

```
select *
  from dbo.StaffSchedule x
 where not exists (select 'y'
          from dbo.BookedSchedules y
         where y.staffid = x.staffid
           and y.startdatetime = x.startdatetime
           and y.enddatetime = x.enddatetime)
   and not exists (select 'z'
          from dbo.Holidays z
         where cast(z.startdatetime as date) <=
               cast(x.startdatetime as date)
           and cast(z.enddatetime as date) >=
               cast(x.enddatetime as date))
```

Comment: holidays can be range. ex 5th mar - 7th march

Comment: @Billa added logic for a holiday lasting 2+ days